# Writing a regular expression to identify if an input is in XPath syntax

Tags: regex, xpath

I could use some help coming up with a solution for identify inputs in XPath format. Let's say an input could look something like this:

`//*[@id="" or @text="i love stackoverflow" or @name="oh yea" or @class=some-css-class"]`

But the challenge with this is that the XPath value can changes drastically. Please let me know if you have suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the alternative input formats? `.` is a valid XPath expression, but could be confused for a file system reference or a regex pattern

Comment: That's the issue that I'm dealing with. I'd say about 80% of the input formats will be something like:
`//*[@id="lga" or @class=""]`

or

`https://www.amazon.com/`

Answer (score 2):

You could test whether the input string is a valid XPath expression, like so:

```
$string = '//*[@id="" or @text="i love stackoverflow" or @name="oh yea" or @class="some-css-class"]'
try{
    $null = [System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression]::Compile($string)
    # $string is valid XPath
} 
catch {
    # $string is not valid XPath
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's some computer science theory you need to be aware of here. Regular expressions are only capable of analyzing sentences against limited class of grammars, and the grammar of XPath is too complex to fit in that class. You could recognize a simple subset of XPath if that's useful to you, but your best bet is to take an off-the-shelf XPath parser and see whether it accepts the expression as valid. (You also need to think about whether the XPath is semantically valid, e.g. does it contain undeclared variable references or namespace prefixes?)

Comment: Thank you for your input Michael.

Comment: Michael Kay, Are you mean XPath syntax is not a regular language? Are you know the exact category that the language fits in?

Comment: No, sorry, I forget what class of grammar XPath belongs to. According to http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/201101/msg00132.html it's LR(1). But I think that depends on how much intelligence you put into the tokenizer, e.g. to distinguish `*` as an operator from `*` as a wildcard based on context. But the grammar is certainly recursive and therefore not a "regular grammar".